# How to get Annotations for Inbuilt Package Functions in Python

Tags: python, function, python-typing

We know that we can use `__annotations__` to get annotations for user defined function or variables. But, how to get annotations for inbuilt or installed functions.

There are tools, like - *Pylance* in *vscode*, which generate annotations for even inbuilt functions (probably, using extra typing files).

How can I get these annotations at runtime in python?

Comment: You might be looking for `typing.get_type_hints`, which is probably the "correct" way to do this.

Comment: What do you need this for?

Comment: @AKX Actually, I want to generate `Nodes` for *visual programming* in python.

Comment: @chepner `typing.get_type_hints` returns `Empty`  dict for me.

Comment: @MohitSaini Okay. You will probably need to parse the standard-library `pyi` type stubs then: https://github.com/python/typeshed/tree/main/stdlib

Comment: @AKX I'm just looking at the *same repository*. I think `mypy` create a syntax tree and parse `pyi`. Do you know something about this?

Comment: Pylance, mypy, and other type checkers each [ship with a copy of typeshed](https://github.com/python/typeshed). To programmatically extract type hints from typeshed, you either (1) need one of the Python-based type checkers as a runtime dependency (e.g. [mypy](https://github.com/python/mypy/tree/master/mypy/typeshed) or [pytype](https://github.com/google/pytype/blob/407037c3ee2e351659402c97ac95f5c76d38880f/setup.py#L52), *not* pylance as it is a TypeScript library) or (2) somehow have typeshed as a runtime dependency.